# Matplotlib animation: How to erase previously plotted point?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am acquiring and plotting latitudes and longitudes. I am able to animate it on the plot but i want the previously plotted point to be erased before the next one gets plotted. Also how do i break the animation and go to the rest of the code (e.g elif statement below) Here is the structure of my code:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.stock_img()
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, color='black', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)


def calc(i)

#Here the latitude.degrees and longitude.degrees are calculated (acquired)

plt.scatter(longitude.degrees, latitude.degrees, color='Red', marker='o')


while True:


        if some condition:
          anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, calc, interval=100, blit=False)

          plt.show()

        elif some other condition: # I never get to this statement. If i close plot, the entire Gui 
                                   #closes

          some other code

window.close() # I am using pysimplegui
```

Answer (score 0):

If your previous axis element, e.g. `ax.plot(..,..)` is stored in a variable `line`. Then you can remove it as follows:

```
line = ax.plot(..,..)
for l in line:
    l.remove()
    del l
```